# Enumerating both Network Drives and Network locations on a Windows PC

Tags: c#, windows, networking, wmi

I'm attempting to enumerate all types of "Network storage" from a windows PC using C#. So far I can successfully list all "Network Drives", but "Network Locations" do no show in the list.

I'm currently using WMI - Win32_MappedLogicalDisk, which in this case:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Qic3XNt.png]

Returns just the Z: Drive.

However, if I use CMD - net use, it returns both locations.

So my question is: Is there a better way to get the entire list of connected places rather than just scraping the output from net use.

Thanks.